# How can I reverse my wifi from monitor mode to normal mode?

Tags: wifi-hardware-switch, hacking

In a course named ethical Hacking for beginners , I learned that wifi has some modes in which we can switch between but I don't know that what was the normal mode and how to switch on it

I used following commands :-

```
ifconfig wlo1 down
iwconfig wlo1 mode monitor
ifconfig wlo1 up
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed mode is what you want:

```
$ sudo ifconfig wlo1 down
$ sudo iwconfig wlo1 mode managed
$ sudo ifconfig wlo1 up
```

And then restart networking:

```
$ sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: since `ifconfig` is obsolete now (no longer installed), maybe you could update this to use `ip link set wlo1 down` etc. This would also get around the problem that your edit made this answer extremely similar to velix's (although I think the `sudo`s in your version are needed).

Answer (score 7):

The "normal" mode is called managed. Just type:

```
ifconfig wlo1 down
iwconfig wlo1 mode managed
ifconfig wlo1 up
```

You may need to restart some services that you killed:

```
service network-manager restart
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Run:

   ```
   sudo airmon-ng stop wlan0mon
   ```
2. Make sure your adapter is showing up. If it's not up, run:

   ```
   ifconfig wlan0 up
   ```
3. Restart the services that you killed.
4. Run:

   ```
   service NetworkManager start
   ```

Note: `service network-manager start` will give a message saying it's not installed. Hence, run:

```
sudo service NetworkManager start
```

Your Wi-Fi adapter should restart at this point, so give it a second to show up.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem but what fixed it for me was

```
Sudo apt-get install - - reinstall network-manager
```

I hope this helps,
Some useful commands I've learned along this journey are

// lspci / displays pci //

Lsusb / ports //

Netstat - I /network services //

Ip link show / can display your wlan0 card if not detected by ifconfig

// Lspci also helps //

Rfkill show all / my laptop had a "hard block" button that had an override over my wlan0, pressing ctrl c fixed this for me //

Iwconfig / was used to check the status of my wlan0 card //

Airmon-ng / showed my wlan0 card type as I originally thought it was a driver issue //

Dhclient wlan0 / started a dhcp client as to try to resume connectivity //
//WL-

Answer (score -1):

3 year-old question, but none of the answers seem to work anymore.
What you want to do is run:

```
sudo airmon-ng stop wlp3s0mon
sudo service network-manager restart
```

replace wlp3s0mon with your wifi adapter name. Mine gets renamed from wlp3s0 to wlp3s0mon so I use that (this is when running wifite2).
I even put the two commands into a bash script so I can double-click on it. It'll ask for root password, do its thing, and close the terminal.